Azure - Error expanding msix app attach package. failed on all Session Hosts that it was sent to. Session Host: , Virtual disk not found at
I get:
Error expanding msix app attach package. The MSIX Application metadata expand request failed on all Session Hosts that it was sent to. Session Host: , Virtual disk not found at
≤//shareddrive/xxx.vhdx≥.
When I in azure try to add Microsoft_Azure_WVD
At tab "Image path"
I have selected
Storage account
shareddrive
And:
File share
xxx.vhdx (size 1.6 GB)
